# Are new conventions for namings or illustrations publishable?

Tags: publications

I am an undergrad student, and the paper writing is not involved in curricula here. Nobody  even talks about it seriously at undergraduate level at my place.

I have derived some conventions/names which to me seems that they are provide a lot of convenience in illustrations/communications. Admittedly, these are just that - notations. No drastic new formula, or framework or anything like that. But their appeal feels a lot to me. I have searched over the internet, and they don't seem to be already known.

The conventions for ease in illustrations are in the field of chemistry. And the names are in mathematics which bleed a lot into physics too.

I want to know - is this kind of stuff publishable? I mean yes, in the past, it has been. Like we have lots of projections in chemistry, and same for maths. But is it so in the current times too, especially that those concerned fields are already mature enough?

And what approach to take for articles for such notational improvements?

By trying to pre-publishing (or whatever apt process it is), I want to mainly fulfill 3 goals:

- get those out in public in a formal manner and maybe receive feedback (or in worse case backlash lol)
- get my paws wet with the general procedure of publishing
- move on in life from that stuff (ticking it off from the mental to-do list). I am holding onto these over myself for over a year now, and I really want it to reach a definite conclusion.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not appropriate for this site. My answer: you probably can't publish your nomenclature ideas. When you reach a point where you have actual new results that are best expressed with your new vocabulary you might try to get that vocabulary accepted by defining and using it when you publish your research.

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted so badly, seems like a legit question. Maybe my edits will help. In any case, my answer [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/165666/79875) may be a bit relevant.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone. I am reading through all the inputs and processing. I will do the required action (marking accepted answer or coming up with an update/reply etc) in some days after I think it out :sweat_smile:

Answer (score 0):

It is doubtful that such a thing could be published on its own, other than on an informal site like ArXiv or a personal site. But what is publishable is up to the publisher. For the most part, publishers want to publish advances driven by research rather than what you propose.

If you included (some of your) ideas in a research paper or even in an expository work on some subfield of interest in industry or academia it would have a higher chance to appear, but the decision would center on the other things you write, not the terminology and such that you use.

But, as an undergraduate, you have an opportunity to discuss what you are doing with a trusted faculty member and get some advice on where to take it.