# I've begun inventing a system for naming binary numbers. Is it worth writing a paper?

Tags: mathematics, computer-science, research-undergraduate

I'm an undergrad computer science student. In my spare time, I was playing with binary numbers and realized that there was no way to think about a binary number without either converting it to decimal, or hexadecimal, or resorting to droning off a long string of "one zero zero zero one one zero one zero."

I thought of a way to be able to name any binary number of arbitrary size using units I call Tolkiens. If anyone is interested in the details, I'd be happy to explain what I have so far, even just for curiosity's sake. I'm just wondering if anyone else thinks it's worth putting in some effort to study the need and acceptance of the new naming convention and publish a paper for the scientific community.

Comment: Part of me keeps wondering - there *is* a naming for binary numbers of arbitrary size. For instance, 1110 is called "14". Why is it easier to remember that it's called (say) "Oblash" and then that "Oblash" represents 14?

Comment: That's a naming convention for decimal numbers, not binary. You have to convert in order to use those names. The name "twenty-four" tells you that the visual representation is a 2 followed by a 4, i.e. 24. It tells you nothing about the binary representation.

Comment: Binary numbers are for the computers to read. What's the use case for your naming convention ?

Comment: @Nobody Well, there are some niche cases in cryptography and assembly language programming where it might be used more often, but I think that most computer science students could benefit from an alternative way of thinking about binary numbers without having to convert back and forth all the time. I wouldn't have thought of it if I didn't want it myself.

Comment: Whatever you call them, they are simply constants. Abstract concepts are more important for you to explore.

Comment: I could swear we've already had the same question ("I've invented a new system for naming binary numbers, is this publishable") either here or on MathOverflow, of course with a different naming system. Anyone remember which question I'm talking about? In any case, for sure you're not the first person to come up with such a system. I get that it was a fun experience coming up with such a system, but the reason that no such naming system is in use is that there is no need for it, not that it's difficult to come up with.

Comment: @AdamPřenosil I mean, it's not a completely useless idea, but if it's been researched before and shown to be unhelpful, then I guess I should have done more research before asking this question.

Comment: Of course, if so many members of the community I want to share my ideas with are pushing back so hard, there's probably no chance of it catching on and I'll probably just use it for myself and not put a lot of effort into the details. Maybe I'll explore the question more if I can work it into a project for one of my future classes. Thanks everyone for your input.

Comment: Probably the main reason you're getting such hard push back is because you asked if you should write a paper on it. Papers are for much more complicated and deeper ideas than basic naming conventions (some fields may have need of naming conventions but they'll be much more complex than this kind of convention). If you'd said "should I write a blog post", the response might have been "I don't think it will catch on, but if it helped you it might help someone else, so could be worth doing".

Comment: It's trivial to look at a binary number as an octal or hexadecimal number. Zero conversion required, and then you have all the naming you want.

Comment: Here is the other proposal that was at the back of my mind: https://forum.artofmemory.com/t/a-major-system-based-mnemonic-for-a-way-of-pronouncing-binary-numbers/77418 Incidentally, I don't understand the downvotes. The OP, as an undergrad, was not sure whether this is something that is at the level of a publishable result, so he asked in a forum where more experienced people can give him some feedback. What exactly is the problem with that? Surely people should be encouraged to ask such questions if they are unsure how publishing an academic paper works?

Comment: @AdamPřenosil Here you go: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/165622/109931. And related questions by the same fellow.

Comment: Come on, people. This question is downvoted like it is seriously horrible. Can you name the reasons? Or is it just because a newbie doesn't know what publishing means? (+1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Broadly, I'd say no. When you think about numbers from a mathematical perspective, there is a one to one mapping from binary/hexadecimal to decimal numbers, so you can always simplify by using that naming convention if you want to say it out loud. Research papers are for more fundamental ideas than just what to name something.

If you keep playing around with it and find it useful in a significant way, a blog post would be more appropriate. If it actually is more useful then it may get adopted, if not it will just float around with a couple of people (or just one) using the convention.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I know that it's possible to look at a number like 1001 and know that it's 9, but sometimes you don't really need to know that it's 9. You just need to know that it's 1001. And for people like me, a number like 10100110 is going to take a lot longer to transcribe if I have to convert it to decimal or remember it as "one zero one zero zero one one zero," even if I take a hexadecimal shortcut. However, "tenty-ten tolkiens, onety-ten" tells you exactly what the visual representation of the number is, even if it sounds silly. It also has other benefits but i ran out of space

Comment: If you're talking about these numbers a lot, you'll probably be able to quickly convert to hex and back. And it requires effort to learn this new naming scheme (which isn't useful if no one around you can understand it). But when you work in research these numbers will become unimportant; they are just tools to represent deeper concepts. As an example, arithmetic becomes less important in higher level mathematics since you are interested in describing over-arching mathematical structures rather then adding some numbers together. I could also say hex A-six, which I'd find easier to remember.

Comment: But then you're relying on whoever you're talking to being able to quickly convert between hex and binary. I know it only requires memorizing sixteen binary patterns or a quick 4-bit conversion, but wouldn't it be even more helpful if each of those patterns had a unique name which also happened to describe the number's digits? We have a system for that in decimal and nobody questions it.

Comment: More likely someone in that field would know that conversion, and even if not they would be able to quickly remember the hex (since they know numbers and letters already). Also it doesn't need to be quick unless they have to write it in binary right away. If I say initialise with e5, you don't need to do that conversion until you are writing it down (and then tools/macros make this easier). And its easier to remember a string in base 16 instead of base 4 (just as base 4 is easier than base 2).

Comment: Really, the system is most useful if you have to copy a large amount of binary data and copy-paste is not available, but that's not the only time it's useful. At its core, a naming convention provides a way of thinking about binary numbers without any conversions at all. In reality, thinking of numbers in binary should be as easy as thinking of numbers in decimal or hexadecimal. But converting a 64-bit binary number to hexadecimal by hand just to shout it across the room is insanity, even if that situation only comes up once in a blue moon.

Comment: In edge cases like that, you don't need anything standardised, each group can have their own form. But also keep in mind that you are no longer thinking in binary, you're thinking in quadary since you're base 4 when you're grouping two bits together. Coming up with other names for hex numbers that are easier to associate with the binary might be more useful, e.g. 1001 is pool or something similar because there are two pillers near a hole (filled with water). Then this becomes an adjustment to hex (well known) that helps with conversion (which is your goal).

Comment: @AnthonyZeedyk PS: as a rule of thumb, it's considered best practice to wait a day or so on this site before accepting an answer, someone might come along in a couple of hours or so and write a better/more general answer than what I quickly wrote. Not really important here but just to let you know for next time since you're new ;)